# Approximate orthogonality between sine and cose

Tags: trigonometry, orthogonality, trigonometric-integrals

#### Given

Two signals

\begin{align}
   s_1(t) = \sin(2\pi ft)
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
   s_2(t) = \cos(2\pi ft)
\end{align}

are defined for $t \in [0 T)$

#### Question

The task is to show that $s_1(t)$ and $s_2(t)$ are approximately orthogonal if $f >> 1/T$

#### Attempted solution

For orthogonality we must have that the inner product is equal to zero, that is

\begin{align}
   \langle s_1, s_2 \rangle = \int_0^T s_1(t)s_2(t)dt = 0
\end{align}

explicitly we have

\begin{align}
   \int_0^T s_1(t)s_2(t)dt = \int_0^T \sin(2\pi ft)\cos(2\pi ft)dt
\end{align}

Using the trigonometric identity $\sin2\theta = 2\sin\theta\cos\theta$ we have

\begin{align}
   \int_0^T \frac{1}{2}\sin (4\pi ft)dt = \bigg [\frac{-cos(4\pi ft)}{8\pi f}\bigg ]_0^T = -\frac{1}{8\pi f}(\cos(4\pi fT) -1) 
\end{align}

If we set this expression to 0 we must have that $\cos(4\pi ft) - 1 = 0$, or

\begin{align}
   \cos(4\pi fT) = 1
\end{align}

or

\begin{align}
   4\pi fT = 2\pi 
\end{align}

or

\begin{align}
   f = \frac{1}{2T}
\end{align}

This doesn't make sense with the given condition, I mean why should $f$ be much bigger than $1/T$?

Answer (score 1):

What you've shown is that *if* $f=1/(2T)$, then the two functions are orthogonal. However, what you're asked to do is show that if the frequency is far greater than $1/T$, the functions are approximately orthogonal. I would think the [Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma) might be useful here. You could probably take the real part of a complex exponential to get what you need.